# how to get the field name of the forms section that I have in firestore to run a json request

Tags: json, google-cloud-firestore, zapier

im working with zapier.com to make a conection between firestore collection to google docs, there is a part to make a StructuredQuery where im getting the 400 error, because he seems not to find the field

I have tried to change the syntax many times, but it seems not to work

**the JSON part:**

```
{
 "orderBy": [{
        "id": {
         "fieldPath": "title"
        },
        "direction": "DESCENDING"
    }]
}
```

**it sends me this:**

```
We had trouble finding a sample.
Error code 400: [{

  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"id\" at 'structured_query.order_by[0]': Cannot find field.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "field": "structured_query.order_by[0]",
            "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"id\" at 'structured_query.order_by[0]': Cannot find field."
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
]
```

[the firebase part that i try to reach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFs78.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution for anyone that found this helpfull

```
{
 "orderBy": [{
         "field": {    
                    "fieldPath": "id"
                },
        "direction": "DESCENDING"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
{
  "orderBy": [
    {
      "field": {
        "fieldPath": "name" //name is the field in you document.
      },
      "direction": "DESCENDING"
    }
  ]
}
```